# Set locales in android

Tags: android, locale, android-location

In the Setting application, when choosing Language & keypad then Select a language, I find a list of many languages (English, French, Japanese, ...) about 30 languages. But I only want to find about 10 languages of my choice. In the Language setting application, I found this code :

```
String[] locales = getAssets().getLocales();
```

I think this code brings the locale from android internal class. So how to modify it to only bring locales that I want ( English, French, Spanish ...)
Thanks

Comment: have read this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: You mean, you want to restrict the languages which the user can set for the system? Or which come into effect for your app?